# Security.salt value in controller

Tags: php, security, cakephp, hash, cakephp-2.0

In cakephp there is one file core.php
It contains

```
Configure::write('Security.salt', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
```

How can i get the value of Security.salt in controller in cakephp.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try like this

```
Configure::read('Security.salt');
```

it will give you the value. For more info check [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#Configure%3a%3aread)

Comment: This method works pre 3.x, take a look at my below answer for CakePHP 3.x.

Answer (score 4):

The above answers have not proven to be successful in CakePHP3.

`Configure::Read('Security.salt')` will return a blank value.

In-order to read the salt from the configuration file you'll need to include the Security namespace:

`use Cake\Utility\Security;`

And you can retrieve the value of the salt using:

`Security::salt()`

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
Configure::read("Security.salt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get `Security.salt` value from below given url

http://www.sethcardoza.com/tools/random-password-generator/

Use 40 char long Salt

`Configure::write('Security.salt','#IDjVn^BeZQ_kK)V5oFzk#s&8LSq44zVqN36SP^T');`