# fetch security salt in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.4

I read documents and I am not able to get it how to get `Security.salt` value from `app.php` in `Cakephp 3`. I am trying to get it like this

```
$salt = Configure::read('Security.salt');
```

Importing following libraries

```
use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Core\Configure\Engine\PhpConfig;
```

Kindly help.

`Cakephp version is 3.4`

Comment: You can see my previous answer for Reading the salt in Cakephp 3.x, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19044944/security-salt-value-in-controller/36239832#36239832

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Configure::Read('Security.salt')` will return a blank value in cakephp 3.x before cakephp 3 version it worked.

In-order to read the salt from the configuration file you'll need to include the Security namespace:

```
use Cake\Utility\Security;
```

And you can retrieve the value of the salt using:

```
Security::salt()
```

**Example-**

```
 echo Security::salt();
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
// Security::salt() is deprecated as of 3.5.0 Use getSalt()/setSalt() instead.
<?php
use Cake\Utility\Security;

function yourMethod() {
    echo Security::getSalt();
}
```